# Add hostname to the springboot /info actuator

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have incorporated `git-commit-id-maven-plugin` to capture the commit version id in my springboot applicatin.
The `/actuator/info` endpoint now returns the following

```
{"git":{"branch":"feature/AddActuator","commit":{"id":"ebd8af6","time":"2022-05-19T18:15:00Z"}}}
```

**I would also like to add the hostname as well to the /info** along with the above response, so that I can confirm which the versions in all the deployed hosts in a distributed environment.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: The application generally doesn't know its own hostname.

Comment: Yup, I understand that. But I was checking if the /info endpoint could add the hostname details too - that should be possible

Answer (score 0):

In order to add the additional `/info` variables, you might inject additional `InfoContrubitor` that will display the hostname:

```java
@Component
public class HostnameContributor implements InfoContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
        try {
            builder.withDetail("hostname", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
        } catch (UnknownHostException exception) {
            builder.withDetail("hostname", "unknown");
        }
    }
}
```